# Make a function go back at the top

Tags: python-3.x

Python 3.10.4

How can i make this function go back to the top of the loop after his execution?

When pyautogui find the "file1.png" he do some stuff and i need the code go back to the top of the loop after his execution.

How can i make this function go back to the top of the loop?

```
def function3():

#stuff 1
pyautogui.click(x=612, y=263)

time.sleep(2)

#stuff 2
pyautogui.click(x=718, y=245)
```

Code:

```
for c in range (0,10):

  #MAKE FUNCTION 3 BACK HERE

  print('BEGIN FOR')

  function1()
  function2()

  while pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('file3.png'):

          function3()

  else:
          pass
#
#
#
#REST OF THE CODE
```

Comment: well, the code goes back automaticly there since the next loop iteration comes. If there's more **inside**  the loop, you could use `continue` statment

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the information, i change the while to if and i put the continue statement after function3() and he back to the top of loop (for)!